# Use OneWire in Python on Raspberry OS

Tags: python

I want to use Python to access OneWire devices directly on my Pi 4b without using the device-file method (open a device file, read its contents, close the file ... for each device on the bus).  Installing the right library/package/whatever on my Pi seems to be a bit more Linux than I have experience for.  Is there a simple set of instructions somewhere for this?

Comment: Why not something like onewire? https://github.com/kipe/python-onewire

Comment: Like other OneWire installs I have attempted, something is missing: onewire/_ow.c:2:10: fatal error: owcapi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <owcapi.h>
I suspect that this is where a "simple" set of instructions stops being simple.